# Javascript Converting an object to another complex variant

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

I currently try to build an animation controller with javascript which sets inline styles based on the current scroll position given by a config object.

For this I try to build a timeline object but I continuous fail.

The following code shows what I am currently doing, what I start with (input) and what I want to archive (output)

```
// this is the config object

const a = document.querySelector('my-elemet-one');
const b = document.querySelector('my-elemet-two');
const c = document.querySelector('my-elemet-three');

const input = [
    {
        element: a,
        frames: {
            0: {
                top: 0
            },
            50: {
                top: 100
            },
            200: {
                top: 400
            }
        }
    },
    {
        element: b,
        frames: {
            100: {
                top: 0
            },
            150: {
                top: 100
            }
        }
    },
    {
        element: c,
        frames: {
            50: {
                top: 0
            },
            150: {
                top: 200
            }
        }
    }
];


(function () {

    let config = {};        // the config parsed to the register method
    let animations = {};    // all keyframes but without any tweens
    let keyframes = [];     // the array with all keyframes when some dom manipulation should happen

    function buildTweens() {
        // here I try to fill up the missing frames between my declared frames
        config.forEach(cfg => {
            let frames = [];
            for(let frame in cfg.hooks) {
                frames.push(parseInt(frame));
            }
            frames.sort((a, b) => a - b);
            let min = frames[0];
            let max = frames[frames.length - 1];
            let missingFrames = [];
            for(let key in animations) {
                let currentFrame = parseInt(key);
                if(currentFrame > min && currentFrame < max) {
                    missingFrames.push(currentFrame);
                }
            }
            missingFrames.forEach(frm => {
                if(typeof cfg.hooks[frm] === 'undefined') {
                    cfg.hooks[frm] = null;
                }
            });
        });

        // here I don't know how to go on


    }

    function register(cfg) {
        cfg.forEach((elm, index) => {
            for (let key in elm.hooks) {
                if (typeof animations[key] === 'undefined') {
                    animations[key] = {};
                }
                const obj = {
                    elm: elm.element,
                    styles: elm.hooks[key]
                }
                animations[key][index] = obj;
            }
        });

        Object.keys(animations).forEach(key => {
            keyframes.push(parseInt(key));
        });

        buildTweens();
    }

    //entry point
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        config = input;
        register(config);
    }, false);
}());

// this is what the object should look like at the end
const output = {
    0: [
        {
            element: a, 
            styles: {
                top: 0
            }
        }
    ],
    50: [
        {
            element: a, 
            styles: {
                top: 100
            }
        },
        {
            element: c,
            styles: {
                top: 0
            }
        }
    ],
    100: [
        {
            element: a, 
            styles: {
                top: 200
            }
        },
        {
            element: b, 
            styles: {
                top: 0
            }
        },
        {
            element: c, 
            styles: {
                top: 100
            }
        }
    ],
    150: [
        {
            element: a, 
            styles: {
                top: 300
            }
        },
        {
            element: b, 
            styles: {
                top: 100
            }
        },
        {
            element: c, 
            styles: {
                top: 200
            }
        }
    ],
    200: [
        {
            element: a, 
            styles: {
                top: 400
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I appreciate any help because I sitting on this conversion since multiple hours and can simply not find a way to finish it